# Rails attr_accessor attribute on parent model available in children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parent-child, attr-accessor

**Context:**

Each Order has many Items & Logistics. Each Item & Logistic (as well as the Order itself) have many Revenues.

I am creating Order + Items & Logistics at once using an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on Order. However, Revenues gets created using an `after_create` callback on each of the models Order, Item, and Logistics. Why? Because given the difference in interpretation in these models, the code reads cleaner this way. (But if this way of doing it is what's causing this question to be asked, I will obviously reconsider!)

One key attribute that I need to store in Revenues is `pp_charge_id`. But `pp_charge_id` is not something that either Order, Items, or Logistics needs to worry about. I've attached an `attr_accessor :pp_charge_id` to Order, so that one works fine, however, once I'm in the child Items or Logistics models, I no longer have access to `pp_charge_id` which again I need to save an associated Revenue. How should I do this?

**Controller Code:**

```
@order = Order.new(params) #params includes Order params, and nested params for child Item & Logistics
@order.pp_charge_id = "cash"
@order.save #I need this to not only save the Order, the children Item & Logistics, but then to also create the associated Revenue for each of the aforementioned 3 models
```

**ORDER Model Code:**

```
has_many :items
has_many :revenues

attr_accessor :pp_charge_id
after_create :create_revenue

def create_revenue
  self.revenues.create(pp_charge_id: self.pp_charge_id)
end

#This WORKS as expected because of the attr_accessor
```

**ITEM/ LOGISTIC model code:**

```
has_many :revenues
belongs_to :order

after_create :create_revenue

def create_revenue
  self.revenues.create(pp_charge_id: self.order.pp_charge_id)
end

 #This DOES NOT work because self.order.pp_charge_id is nil
```

**ORDER model code:**

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :logistic
```

Again I understand the `attr_accessor` is not designed to persist across a request or even if the Order itself is reloaded. But it also doesn't make sense to save it redundantly in a table that has no use for it. If the only way to do this is to put the `pp_charge_id` into the params for the order and save everything all at once (including Revenues), then let me know because I know how to do that. (Again, would just rather avoid that because of how it's interpreted: params are coming from User, Revenue data is something I'm providing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want the order's `pp_charge_id` to apply to all its items and logistics, I'd put all that into the order's `after_create` callback:

```
# order.rb
def create_revenue
  revenues.create(pp_charge_id: pp_charge_id)
  items.each {|i| i.revenues.create(pp_charge_id: pp_charge_id)}
  logistics.each {|l| l.revenues.create(pp_charge_id: pp_charge_id)}
end
```

**EDIT**: Alternately, you could add `inverse_of` to your `belongs_to` declarations, and then I believe `Item#create_revenue` would see the same `Order` instance that you set in the controller. So if you also added an `attr_accessor` to the `Item` class, you could write its `create_revenue` like this:

```
# item.rb
def create_revenue
  revenues.create(pp_charge_id: pp_charge_id || order.pp_charge_id)
end
```

This should cover the new requirement you've mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Ah is that the only way? The other thing I should have mentioned is that sometimes I'll create a child on an existing parent like so `@order.items.create(pp_charge_id:"")` and in that case, I will directly pass in a `pp_charge_id` and would like to use the `after_create` callback on the child Item. (This is also reminding me I need to use an `attr_accessor :pp_charge_id` on the child Item)

Comment: @james I added an alternative that should meet both approaches.

Comment: `inverse_of` worked! it's weird though... i thought that may have been the answer, but then I read around and saw that Rails 4 auto infers the `inverse_of`. Guess in this case, the magic didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `after_create` and accessors you should consider having a proper method that does exactly what you need, ie:

```
Order.create_with_charge(:cash, params)
```

i find it disturbing to persist redundant information in the database just because the code reads cleaner that way!

Comment: That's fair, but in your custom method, how would you pass the first `cash` param to the Revenue that is created on the child Item/ Logistic model?